# Read date from Core Data attribute

Tags: php, swift, core-data

I have a sqlite database generated by Core Data.

I need read a field type Date with PHP and convert it into DateTime. The field in Core Data has a value like: `631170000`.

```
<attribute name="date" attributeType="Date" defaultDateTimeInterval="-978278400" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
```

How can I transform this `defaultDateTimeInterval` double value into a Date?

Comment: UnixTimestamp ? https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: Is this a php or a swift question?

Comment: If the field uses Date type, it should be converted to a Swift Date automatically. How are you getting that value?

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading Core Data persistent stores in PHP, you're setting yourself up for difficulty, because those files are not designed to be read directly. Core Data is not simply a SQLite wrapper, and the structure of the tables and data types it uses in SQLite are not documented and may not be what you expect. If it's at all possible to read the data using Core Data and then send it to your server running PHP, do that, because otherwise you'll end up reverse-engineering parts of Core Data since you're directly reading a file not designed to be used that way.

Dates are one of the simpler cases. Core Data saves them as the number of seconds since midnight on December 31, 2000, UTC. It's not a Unix timestamp but it's the same idea with a different reference date.

There might be a PHP library or some open source code to convert. If not, the difference between Apple's reference date and a Unix timestamp is 978307200 seconds. To convert the number in your question, add 631170000 + 978307200 and treat the result as a Unix timestamp.

But really, if there's any way you can use Core Data to read and convert the data, do that instead, you'll save yourself trouble.